# SystemC cannot use "+" "-" operators in visual studio 2019

Tags: systemc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALQmE.png)
I am trying to build the counter, when the "dec1" signal is high, the 8-bit unsign integer counter will decrese by 1. I am using visual sidio 2019 to complie the counter.cpp file, and "Hello worlds" .cpp is successful to run.

Comment: Please have a look at how to ask add a good example of code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you try `counter1 = counter1 + 1;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

systemc cannot do signal op,
so every thing should have incomming signal and do the type casting.

sc_in  > counter;

counter = counter + 1; //will not work

sc_uint<16> local_counter = counter.read(); //this will work

local_counter = local_counter + 1; //will work

Answer (score 1):

A SystemC signal does not provide access to all member functions of its internal value type, only an implicit conversion. You'll need to write the long form of

```cpp
  counter1 = counter1 + 1;
```